# SQL Query value always negative

Tags: sql, oracle, negative-number

I'm trying to write a SQL query to show me both In and Out transactions within our database. There is a field in the database called In_Out but the problem is that the values for Out transactions are a mix of positive numbers and negative numbers depending on how the user made the transaction. I need a Query that would make the Out numbers always be negative without changing the already negative numbers to positive, so I don't think *-1 would work.

I need all these numbers the be negative so that when the value is multiplied by Std_Cost the value of the adjustment is correctly shown as a negative adjustment.

Thanks!

Comment: Most (if not all) databases can get you the absolute number - so the simplest way to do it would be something like this: `SELECT -1 * ABS(In_Out) As In_Out ...`

Comment: Which database engine are you using? (MySQL, Prostgres, Oracle, etc.) Please add the tag for it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use abs x -1 to always return negative

```
Select abs(num) * -1;
```